Taylor expansion of logarithm
I've been asked to solve the following exercise: consider the function $f(x) = \log(4 + x^2)$. Obtain its Taylor expansion centered in $x = 0$.
I've tried to solve this through a change of variables: let's call $u(x) = 3 + x^2$ and use the Taylor expansion of $\log(1 + x)$ centered in $x = 0$. However, if we do this we'll obtain the following series:
$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k + 1} \frac{(3 + x^2)^k}{k}$
which diverges in $x = 0$. I think my mistake here is that the variable $u \neq 0$ when $x = 0$, so in order for this method to be correct, I would have to use the Taylor expansion of $\log(1 + x)$ centered in $x = 3$. The problem is, I don't know this expansion. And, even if I did, I honestly doubt it would work, given the differences between $u$ (quadratic) and $x$ (linear).
What is my mistake, and does anyone know how to proceed?

Hint: $4+x^2 = 4\left(1+\frac{x^2}{4}\right)$

Expand the derivative and then integrate without forgetting F(0).

As $u=3+x^2$ and we want the Taylor Series around $x=0$, we would need to find the series for $\ln(1+u)$ at $u=3$.
An alternative is noticing that $\ln(4+x^2)=\ln(4)+\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{4}\right)$.
The Taylor Series for $\ln(1+x)$ around $x=0$ is famously known to be $$\ln(1+x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}x^k}{k}$$
for $|x|<1$. Plugging in $\dfrac{x^2}{4}$ we get $$\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{4}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}x^{2k}}{k4^k}$$
for $\frac{x^2}{4}<1$, that is, $|x|<2$.
We conclude that $$\ln(4+x^2)=\ln(4)+\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{4}\right)=\ln(4)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}x^{2k}}{k4^k}$$ for $|x|<2$.
